# python3.5 : No module named 'twisted.enterprise'

Tags: python-3.x, twisted

I am using python`3.5.2`,there is a sentence in `demo.py`,as follow:

```
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
```

There is an error when running:

```
    from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
ImportError: No module named 'twisted.enterprise'
```

What should I do?

Comment: What does `import twisted; print(twisted)` produce?

Comment: @MartijnPieters `print(twisted)` : `<module 'twisted' from 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\twisted\\__init__.py'>`

Comment: Was that done from within the script that raised that exception? Does the `C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\twisted\enterprise` directory exist?

Comment: @MartijnPieters  No,it doesn't exist.Was it  changed in new version?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Maybe I should download it from github.

Comment: No, the package is not new; it sounds as if your installation is incomplete. Re-install it from scratch perhaps?

Comment: ``adbapi`` hasn't been officially bundled with Twisted yet, but work is done and it will likely ship with the next 16.4 release.  If you simply cannot wait, then I'd suggest you download Python 2.7 and use that for the time being.  If it makes you feel any better, I'm waiting on that package too :)